# Alamofire request not working in Swift 4 project

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am trying to trigger a GET request using Alamofire and Swift using example code provided on Swift.org and the Alamofire GitHub page. Apparently, the request does not get executed.

Environment:

- macOS 10.13.3
- Swift 4.0.3
- Alamofire 4.6.0
- Xcode 9.2

First, I [create a new executable](https://swift.org/getting-started/#using-the-package-manager) package:

```
[u@h ~/swift]$ mkdir Foo
[u@h ~/swift]$ cd Foo/
[u@h ~/swift/Foo]$ swift package init --type executable
Creating executable package: Foo
Creating Package.swift
Creating README.md
Creating .gitignore
Creating Sources/
Creating Sources/Foo/main.swift
Creating Tests/
```

Alamofire gets [added as a dependency](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#swift-4) in `Package.swift`:

```
// swift-tools-version:4.0
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Foo",
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git", from: "4.0.0")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "Foo",
            dependencies: ["Alamofire"]),
    ]
)
```

Then I add [the example code](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#response-handling) to `main.swift`:

```
import Alamofire

print("Hello, world!")

Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get").responseJSON { response in
    print("Request: \(String(describing: response.request))")   // original url request
    print("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))") // http url response
    print("Result: \(response.result)")                         // response serialization result

    if let json = response.result.value {
        print("JSON: \(json)") // serialized json response
    }

    if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        print("Data: \(utf8Text)") // original server data as UTF8 string
    }
}

print("Goodbye, world!")
```

After that I try to run it:

```
[u@h ~/swift/Foo]$ swift run
Fetching https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git
Cloning https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git
Resolving https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git at 4.6.0
Compile Swift Module 'Alamofire' (17 sources)
Compile Swift Module 'Foo' (1 sources)
Linking ./.build/x86_64-apple-macosx10.10/debug/Foo
Hello, world!
Goodbye, world!
```

As you can see, none of the `print` statements in the Alamofire example code gets executed. The request does not get executed either, which can be observed when the `Alamofire.request` call points to a local web server.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `DispatchGroup` to wait for the network request's completion:

```
import Alamofire
import Foundation

print("Hello, world!")

let group = DispatchGroup()

group.enter()
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get").responseJSON { response in
    // handle the response
    group.leave()
}

group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
    print("Goodbye, world!")
    exit(0)
}
dispatchMain()
```