# JSON POST request with Alamofire 4.6 is not firing

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am trying to send a post request with Alamofire 4.6. I am having an issue where it does not seem like the body of the request is never being reached. The server Is never getting a request and the print statements are never being hit. I am led to believe that the request is never started up.

```
 let jsonData = ["request":
            ["method": "phoneNumberVerificationStart","id": 1,
             "params":
                ["number": "\(PhoneNumber)"] ]]


 let urlString = "*************************************"

 let requestURL = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlString)!)

 let finalRequest = Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: jsonData, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
      finalRequest.responseJSON{
                request in
                print(request)
                print("I am IN the request")

            }

        print("Here after Request")
```

The "Here after the Request" prints out but the "I am IN the request" never is hit so I am led to believe that the async call is never called. Does anyone have an idea what the issue is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alamofire request not working in Swift 4 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48720001/alamofire-request-not-working-in-swift-4-project)

Comment: See if this response helps you. It helped me address a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/48720156/3317157